# VueJS Chosen directive does not update on change options

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, jquery-chosen

I am trying to fill my jQuery Chosen dropdown field through AJAX using VueJS, however when I apply the new values it does not update the Chosen dropdown.

I have tried multiple things such as manually triggering `$('.cs-select').trigger("chosen:updated");` when we get the AJAX response however I think this does not work since VueJS needs a few seconds to parse the results to all dropdowns (I have about 20 with the same values on one page).

Here an example where it does not work, I am adding the city Amsterdam once everything is ready however only shows up in the none-JS dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/qfy6s9Lj/106/

Anyone got an easy fix? I feel like using `setTimeout()` is not the way to go.

Comment: id recommend just making it a component and using a watch on the data you want to update to trigger your jquery update. components are much more powerful than directives and you can place the select as the root element of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, but it will take a bit of work. First if you update to using the 1.0 version of Vue you have access to a params value which would allow you to set up a watcher for when you add items to you `cities` array reference (https://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#params). However, you will need use `v-for` to list out the options since in 1.0 you need to manually write out the option elements https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select

I believe the reason it isn't working. Is because when the options change in your custom directive there is nothing listening for that change. The `update` function only listens to changes to the variable supplied to `v-chosen`.

Depending on your needs and time frame you may want to upgrade all the way to 2.0. It is still in beta, but is nearing official release. In 2.0 you would create a custom component to handle plugins eg (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/examples/select2/index.html) this was a directive in 1.0 and now is a component in 2.0.